# Python list of dicts: how to manipulate dynamically?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Is it possible to make a list of dicts such a way that when I change the dicts' content, the containing list reflects it (in spite of just storing in a copy of the original dict)?

```
a = {1: 1, 2, 2}
b = {3: 3, 4: 4}
c = [a, b]
c
[{1: 1, 2, 2}, {3: 3, 4: 4}]
a = {1: 6, 2: 7}
c
[{1: 1, 2, 2}, {3: 3, 4: 4}]
```

and not

```
[{1: 6, 2: 7}, {3: 3, 4: 4}]
```

(My goal is to have a 2D table-like structure that can be navigated both horizontally and vertically, and to avoid refreshing cols and rows after each new value entered in any cell. I need pointer-like behavior)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update `a` in-place using [`update()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) as opposed to reassigning it:

```
a.clear()
a.update({1: 6, 2: 7})
```

(See also: [`clear()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.clear))

---

Using your full example:

```
>>> a = {1: 1, 2: 2}
>>> b = {3: 3, 4: 4}
>>> c = [a, b]
>>> c
[{1: 1, 2: 2}, {3: 3, 4: 4}]
>>> a.clear()
>>> a.update({1: 6, 2: 7})
>>> c
[{1: 6, 2: 7}, {3: 3, 4: 4}]  # <--
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
a = {1: 6, 2: 7}
```

you just reassigning variable `a`, so it'll point to new dict, and variable `c` is not modified at all. Previous value of `a` is left only as first element of `c`.

So you have to either change element of `c`, like:

```
c[0] = {1: 6, 2: 7}
```

or change elements of `a` (but not reassign `a`):

```
a[1], a[2] = 6, 7
```

or

```
a.update({1:6, 2:7})
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reassigning `a` you could modify it in place.

```
a[1] = 6
a[2] = 7
```